# matrix calculation in excel without editing the place of $ symbol

Tags: excel

assume that I need to fill the matrix in range of B2 - F6 with formula that (most left value of the row x most top value of the column).

to do this

1. I need to use $ symbol in function bar
2. place of the $ symbol will differ between these two actions (while I
   pull down from B2 to B6 AND while I pull right from B column to F
   column)

is there any way to do this matrix calculation (filling from B2 to F6) without editing the places of $ symbol. I mean set one cell formula, then only pull down and pull right (or vice verse)

regards

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In B2, for example, you can use this formula:

```
=B$1*$A2
```

Dragging it anywhere in the matrix will get you the products you're looking for, if I have understood correctly. By placing the `$` in front of the 1 in `B$1`, you're locking down the row, but not the column. And by using `$A2`, with `$` in front of the A, you're locking down the column, but not the row.

Comment: great vision, thanks. so the GOLDEN rule is put $ in front of number for column formula elements & put $ in front of letter for row formula elements, right?

Comment: When you wish to lock them individually, yes. Only put them before both when you want to lock on one specific cell. Good luck!